# bat + shell: copy file to remote server?

Tags: windows, shell, unix, batch-file

I'm trying to create a shell and bat file in which I need to copy some local files to a remote server (I have a Windows and Linux machine).
However there's no DNS so I have to use the IP.

With a bit of googling I found rcp, but the documentation that I've found so far is a bit fuzzy for windows when using the IP.

So I was wondering whether anyone had any suggestions as how to do this in a transparant method without having to install additional applications (scp seems to be unknown to Windows XP but RCP is known).

Comment: shell is running on linux, bat for window, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Automatically copy some files from my Linux or Windows installation to a small server I have running. Just to clarify, I'm not trying to create one hybrid thing that contains both shell and bat. But I'm trying to create a bat file and a shell script that both do the same thing.

Comment: with heterogeneous systems, you are better off getting a tool that can work in different platforms, or a platform independent programming language with the necessary file transfer API (eg Python,Ruby,Perl etc)

Comment: The documentation http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/rcp.mspx?mfr=true seems to be clear enough... Do you have a specific question? Maybe a particular stumbling block?

Comment: I tried the command on Windows using: rcp test1.txt 192.168.1.12.jack:/test as I see on some sites, but that gives me: 192.168.1.12: Connection refused without asking me for a login. Is there a way to force this or must I edit the .rhosts file?

Comment: E.g. `rcp test.txt 127.0.0.1.user:/home/user/test.txt` half-works for me (the windows part works, but i don't have rshd configured in my linux VM so it responds with *Permission denied*).

Comment: *Connection refused* means that either rshd is not running on your target host or firewall is blocking the connection. First of all, try `telnet localhost 514` on Linux; if it doesn't say *Connection refused* - try `telnet 192.168.1.12 514` on Windows.

Comment: In this case the .12 is my windows machine.

Comment: Ah, you're running the command on Linux? In this case you'll need an rsh server on Windows, which is not present by default. Try the reverse: `rcp <Linux-machine-IP>.jack:/home/jack/test .` on Windows machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about ftp?
It is usually enabled on Linux and it is available natively in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

**Batch script - copy files using from a Windows machine**

copy_files.bat

```
@echo off
set FTPSCRIPT=ftpscript.txt
cd C:\src_dir
echo user_name>>%FTPSCRIPT%
echo pasword>>%FTPSCRIPT%
echo cd /dest_dir>>%FTPSCRIPT%
echo binary>>%FTPSCRIPT%
echo hash>>%FTPSCRIPT%
echo prompt n>>%FTPSCRIPT%
echo mput myfiles*.txt>>%FTPSCRIPT%
echo bye>>%FTPSCRIPT%
ftp -s:%FTPSCRIPT% 1.2.3.4
echo y | del %FTPSCRIPT% > nul
```

**Shell script - copy files using from a Unix machine**

copy_files.ksh

```
cd /src_dir
ftp -i -n -v <<EOF
open 1.2.3.4
user user_name password
cd /dest_dir
binary
hash
mput myfiles*.txt
bye
EOF
```